# How to get remaining string after substring deletion in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string `123456789`.

My aim is to get `1236789` after deleting `45`.
I used slice method to delete the string `45`.

```
 var x = 123456789;
 res = x.slice(4, 5); //my output is 45
```

I need the output to be `1236789`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slice before, slice after, and concatenate the resulting strings or [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the 45 with an empty string:

```js
var x = "123456789"
var res1 = x.slice(0, 3) + x.slice(5)

console.log(res1)

var res2 = x.replace('45', '')
console.log(res2)
```

Answer (score 3):

try `replace/2`.

```
"123456789".replace("45", "") /** 1236789 */
```

Or, if your input is an integer and you need and integer as an outcome,

```
var a = 123456789;  
parseInt(a.toString().replace("45", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can so this:

```js
var x = "123456789";
var result = x.substr(0, 3) + x.substr(5);
console.log(result)
```